# Probability Density Function using pandas data

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I would like to model the probability of an event occurring given the existence of the previous event.

To give you more context, I plan to group my data by anonymous_id, sort the values of the grouped dataset by timestamp (ts) and calculate the probability of the sequence of sources (utm_source) the person goes through. The person is represented by a unique anonymous_id. So the desired end goal is the probability of someone who came from a Facebook source to then come through from a Google source etc

I have been told that a package such as sci.py gaussian_kde would be useful for this. However, from playing around with it, this requires numerical inputs.

```
test_sample = test_sample.groupby('anonymous_id').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['ts'])).reset_index(drop=True)
```

and not sure what to try next.
I have also tried this, but i don't think that it makes much sense:

```
stats.gaussian_kde(test_two['utm_source'])
```

Here is a sample of my data

```
    {'Unnamed: 0': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9},
 'anonymous_id': {0: '0000f8ea-3aa6-4423-9247-1d9580d378e1',
  1: '00015d49-2cd8-41b1-bbe7-6aedbefdb098',
  2: '0002226e-26a4-4f55-9578-2eff2999de7e',
  3: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902',
  4: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902',
  5: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902',
  6: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902',
  7: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902',
  8: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902',
  9: '0002ed69-4aff-434d-a626-fc9b20ef1b02'},
 'ts': {0: '2018-04-11 06:59:20.206000',
  1: '2019-05-18 05:59:11.874000',
  2: '2018-09-10 18:19:25.260000',
  3: '2017-10-11 08:20:18.092000',
  4: '2017-10-11 08:20:31.466000',
  5: '2017-10-11 08:20:37.345000',
  6: '2017-10-11 08:21:01.322000',
  7: '2017-10-11 08:21:14.145000',
  8: '2017-10-11 08:23:47.526000',
  9: '2019-06-12 10:42:50.401000'},
 'utm_source': {0: nan,
  1: 'facebook',
  2: 'facebook',
  3: 'google',
  4: nan,
  5: 'facebook',
  6: 'google',
  7: 'adwords',
  8: 'youtube',
  9: nan},
 'rank': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 4, 7: 5, 8: 6, 9: 1}}
```

Note: i converted the dataframe to a dictionary

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave some more details about your data.  In the first two sentences, you refer to "event", "unique id", "values", "timestamp", "sources" and "person", but it is unclear what any of these really mean.

Comment: I have made a few changes, hope it's a bit clearer now? @WarrenWeckesser

Comment: I'm also not sure I completely understand. First `gaussian_kde` works with numerical data (not strings). Are you just looking for the frequency of each `utm_source` per person? Could you give an example of what result you're expecting? If you get an error somewhere, could you also add it? And finally, it would be more helpful that have a dataset with less `nan`, here you just have `facebook` value in your `utm_source`

Comment: @Nakor no the probability of for example someone going from a facebook utm_source to a google utm_source...so looking at the source they came from chronologically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you can do it (if I understand correctly):

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

groups = (df
  .sort_values(by='ts')
  .dropna()
  .groupby('anonymous_id').utm_source
  .agg(list)
  .reset_index()
)

groups['transitions'] = groups.utm_source.apply(lambda x: list(zip(x,x[1:])))
all_transitions = Counter(chain(*groups.transitions.tolist()))
```

Which gives you (on your example data):

```
In [42]: all_transitions
Out[42]:
Counter({('google', 'facebook'): 1,
         ('facebook', 'google'): 1,
         ('google', 'adwords'): 1,
         ('adwords', 'youtube'): 1})
```

Or are you looking for something different?